# How to write Unit test cases for upload, download functionality of Rester services(flask)?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and unit testing,How can i write the unit test cases for below flask[Flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#file-uploads) upload ,[redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) functionality. thanks in advance

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['the_file']
        f.save('/uploaded_file.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a mock object instead of file to request in your test. After it call this method in your test and verify that save method is called at your mock with correct parameters.